# What is the shortcut key to toggle between Suggesting and Editing modes in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

When copying content into Docs, for collaborative editing, there are some changes that I would like to get confirmation on (in Suggesting mode) and others that I want to make silently (in Editing mode). Switching between these states with a mouse is cumbersome. Is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Mode Switch (KB Shortcuts)

| Mode | PC | Mac |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Switch to editing | Ctrl + Alt + Shift + z | ⌘ + Option + Shift + z |
| Switch to suggesting | Ctrl + Alt + Shift + x | ⌘ + Option + Shift + x |
| Switch to viewing | Ctrl + Alt + Shift + c | ⌘ + Option + Shift + c |

The keystroke order is based on [Google Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?hl=en) and the special keys can often be reordered as long as the letter key (`c`, `z`, etc.) is added last to the combination.

#### All KB Shortcuts

1. Online at: [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?hl=en)
2. From within Google Docs:

   - Navigate to **Help > Keyboard shortcuts**; *or*
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (Windows, Chrome OS) or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (Mac)
     <sub>**Help > Keyboard shortcuts > Editing**  ( Windows)</sub>
     [image]

Comment: Updated the accepted answer to cover both use cases (PC/Mac) as well as a note about rearranging the special keys.

Comment: @BlindSpots The Help Center article and on-app dialog keyboard don't match for "Switch to viewing". The article shows `C` while the screenshot shows `D`. On my Mac Mini, with a Spanish keyboard, the one with `D` works.

Comment: @Rubén acknowledged.  You and Driveman seem to agree and I am not a Mac user. Clarified their answer and upvoted.

Comment: @BlindSpots It's bugging me that it's not clear if there was a change or if the help article have been wrong all the time. But not so much as to put my time on this now :)

Comment: @Rubén Also not very slick also mixing the SHIFT  key position between documentation and in-app help which generates confusion without being a material difference.

Answer (score 1):

The viewing mode shortcut (Mac) has now changed to **Shift+Option+Command+D** (it originally used the letter **C**).

Mac Shortcuts

- Editing mode: Shift+Option+Command+Z
- Suggesting mode: Shift+Option+Command+X
- Viewing mode:  Shift+Option+Command+D

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Is there an announcement about this change? How do you know that is permanent and not a glitch / bug? Have you tried the round to find the keyboard shortcut documentation? Maybe MrWonderful answer has a typo. pnuts answer shows keyboard shortcuts for Windows systems.

Comment: It's not a duplicate - the viewing mode shortcut had changed from Shift-Option-Command-C to Shift-Option-Command-D.

That said, I did a poor job highlighting this single change. Editing to fix.

Answer (score 0):

As of today I think the answer has changed. I can't find official documentation for it, but it works on my account

```
Editing mode: Shift-Option-Command-Z

Suggesting mode: Shift-Option-Command-X

Viewing mode:  Shift-Option-Command-C
```

Comment: This keyboard shortcut looks to work for Mac. Are you still using a Mac? What is the current version of MacOS that you are using? Have you tried the route mentioned in the previous answer?

Comment: Your answer doesn't match the documentation and the documentation hasn't changed.  You have simply changed the order of the non-letter keys which in this case doesn't matter as they don't trigger a separate command and nothing happens until the letter key is pressed.